# Burning a used DVD-R

Tags: dvd, bootable-media, dvd-burning

Ok, so here's my situation:

Yesterday,i was making a windows bootable disk from a .iso file using nero. But accidently instead of copying the contents of the .iso file i added it to the disk.When the burn process had just started i realized my mistake and immidiately stopped the process.Now, my disk still have enough space,so i tried to rectify my mistake but the error pops up saying that the disk is not empty.

So my question is can i somehow write anything onto this disk? Is there any software available through which i can use this disk?

P.S.-The disk was not made multi-session(i was making a bootable disk).  I seriously know that i can buy another disk,so please do not post such comments.

Thank You!!

Comment: Get another disk, and use the old one as a coaster?

Comment: Thanks @Journeyman Geek, for your "wise" comment.But i was asking this just out of curiosity...

Comment: Well, disks are dirt cheap (and as things are, USB keys are starting to get more common as installation media). I also believe that the nature of 'burning' a disk image precludes multi session recording.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CD starts with a lead-in part that serves as the index of the disc. All CDs are read starting from that part and it's always in the same place. You have already burnt the lead-in (or at least a part of it) and you can't re-burn it, so you can't burn anything else to that disc.